# JavaScript variable assignment in Azure Bot

Tags: javascript, azure, variables, bots, botframework

I'm creating a bot using Azure BotBuilder and JavaScript and am having the following issue.

I don't know how to capture the value for a button that is pressed in the chat window. In the code below, the 'startOrderCoffee' bot.dialog presents the user with three options for coffees (see pic). When a selection is made by clicking a button, the selection is returned as a message. From the pic, if the user clicks 'Drip coffee', then 'Drip' is shown in the chat window.

What I don't know is how to capture the message value and return that response to the next function. In this case, the button is generated as part of the 'welcomeCard' object and is generated in the chat window via the following session.send() function.

Normally, the results.response option in the second function would capture the previous user input. However, it isn't working here. I've created variables, but it's the assignment that I don't know how to do. Can someone help me understand how to do this?

[image: Coffee buttons and message/error output]

```
// Dialog for ordering a coffee
bot.dialog('startOrderCoffee', [
function (session, args, next) {
    if (!args.continueOrder) {
        session.userData.cart = [];
        session.send("At anytime you can say 'cancel order', 'view cart', or 'checkout'.")
    }
    welcomeCard = new builder.HeroCard(session)
        .title('What kind of coffee would you like?')
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Drip", "Drip coffee"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Espresso", "Espresso coffee"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Mocha", "Mocha")
        ]);
    session.send(new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(welcomeCard));
},
function (session, results) {
    session.beginDialog('add' + results.response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do something that is already packaged and working, called `Prompts`.

In particular, what you are doing should be coded with a `prompt.choice`: see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#promptschoice)

Sample:

```
var salesData = {
    "west": {
        units: 200,
        total: "$6,000"
    },
    "central": {
        units: 100,
        total: "$3,000"
    },
    "east": {
        units: 300,
        total: "$9,000"
    }
};

bot.dialog('getSalesData', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which region would you like sales for?", salesData); 
    },
    function (session, results) {
        if (results.response) {
            var region = salesData[results.response.entity];
            session.send(`We sold ${region.units} units for a total of ${region.total}.`); 
        } else {
            session.send("OK");
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas. I’m aware of the Prompts option and is a good alternative. But it doesn’t solve for wanting to maintain a more graphical, clickable interface.

Comment: Did you use builder.ListStyle.button? That's a generic clickable version

Comment: @Nickolas, I never got around to telling you the builder.ListStyle.button ended up working really well. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

@Steve It looks like you were trying to spin up another dialog to handle the different coffee types. So an alternative would be to create new dialogs and use .triggerAction to catch the button press in the HeroCard:

```
// Dialog to handle Drip Coffee order
bot.dialog('orderDripCoffee', [
    function (session) {
        // handle Drip Coffee order
    }
]).triggerAction({ matches: /Drip/i });
```

Comment: Yes, TomHon! I believe that is what I’m looking for. Thank you! I did some quick research and have a question. I’ve seen a ‘.*’ separating some words for the match. Does that represent a space?

Comment: matches uses Regular Expression syntax - good intro at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: I put together a bot that makes pretty extensive use of the pattern you're looking at - maybe of some use to look at it: https://github.com/tomhon/tovoV0/blob/master/app.js